# How to remove query string from file name using .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

So currently I've got a URL like:

http://test.com/images/1/Villa-1_watermark.jpg&width=132&height=123

Ideally I would like to have a .htaccess file within the images directory which removes the query string ("&width=132&height=123") from all of the images located in the sub-directories.

I currently have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^width=([^&]+)&height=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule . %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R]
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You say `which removes the query string` ¿When? If the incoming URL already holds and shows the query `http://test.com/images/1/Villa-1_watermark.jpg&width=132&height=123`, what would be the purpose of removing it just before fetching the image.

Comment: Well I should say, I'm trying to remove it to prevent the 404 which you currently receive when accessing the images with those parameters passed, as I thought that might solve the problem?

Comment: It's possible that Apache doesn't recognize it as a query string because it doesn't have a leading `?`

Comment: @SeanBright That is actually entirely correct, thanks. Although this still doesn't solve my problem as they are being accessed like that from an external website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apache doesn't recognize `&width=132&height=123` as the query string because it doesn't have a leading `?`.  Try this instead:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule (.*)&.* $1 [L]
```